# How to turn Draw.io Diagrams.net image into a shape

Tags: diagrams

I am working with Draw.io/Diagrams.net tool and I notice that when I search for object two types are returned.  Some seem to be SHAPES and other are IMAGES.  I can drag and drop these onto a canvas.

The biggest issue is that when I search for these shapes there is no way to tell if the search results will return a shape or image.  The biggest difference that I can tell right now between a SHAPE & IMAGE is that a shape can be modified easily.  In this case I am looking to add connections points.

Please see below:

[image]

How do I tell Draw.io to make the IMAGE into a SHAPE so that I can add connection points to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image inside the shape, select both of them, and click `Arrange > Group`  to group them together

Answer (score 0):

a workaround
If you have an image/shape with no connection points you can add them manually:

Inside the "style" tab, click on the dropdown menu "edit" > "edit connection points" and then you can add them and place them around.

Screen capture of the dropdown menu with the connection points option
[image]

The connection points will stay if you copy your image in your scratchpad,
Hope this helps.